# Which HTML CLASS definition is right solution?

Tags: html, css

For now frameworks using for controls something like this

html
`<{{html_tag}} class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" />`

css
`.ui-accordion.ui-widget { {{style}} }
.ui-widget.ui-helper-reset { {{style}} }`

For some time to come to me more logical this

html
`<{{html_tag}} class="ui accordion widget helper reset" />`

css

`.ui.accordion.widget { {{style}} }
.ui.widget.helper.reset { {{style}} }`

Does anyone have any pros and cons?

Comment: It seems odd that `ui-helper-reset` would split into `ui`, `helper` and `reset`.

Comment: Question is [on hold], by "help center", I do not understand how should I rephrase that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, because the framework abbreviation has been added as a prefix to every class specifically *related* to the framework:

1. It allows you to clearly identify framework specific classes (vs what you may have added)
2. It reduces the chance of collision with your own classes
3. The classes are written to specifically relate to purpose, splitting them may abstract the meaning of the class from the purpose

Comment: Thank you SW4. Are you saying that is better to write "button button-small button-image image-ListViewDetail" than "button small image ListViewDetail" ?

Comment: Its all about what is appropriate, if its a framework it is likely more appropriate to prefix...then add a normal class name likely structured dependant on the rest of your CSS. Its about structure and logical sense as much as anything

Answer (score 0):

As well as SW4's answer, it also has the benefit of using the following selectors to select any element with a class that contains or starts with `ui-`, respectively:

`*[class|=ui]` `*[class^=ui-]`

Comment: Thank you Jack Frankland for the good initiative.